# Default root url and display the controller action rather than "/" in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, routes

Is there a way to set the default root routes in rails to be one of my controller action and showing in the url rather than the root "`/`" ?
Say I have a "Computer" controller with a "index" action.

When my user login to my application, I want the url to be

***http://localhost:3000/computer/index*** rather than ***http://localhost:3000/***

```
root :to => "computers#index"
```

does the latter one, how can I make the default root url to be something like the prior one ?

**UPDATE: a better way would be**

> root :to => redirect(/path)

Comment: I simply use the `location` service to dissect the URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be to change which URL your users get re-directed to after they successfully log in.

You could also add a forced re-direct in your controller:

```
# routes.rb
root :to => "computers#force_redirect"

# computers_controller.rb
def force_redirect
  redirect_to '/computers/index'
end
```

Comment: also: _redirect_to computers_path_

with no ' ' :)